# Log shipping from tomcat cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, redis, logstash, log4j2

I'm investigating an issue with the logging system and looking for some input on the possible solutions to the problem.
What we have now:

- Cluster of 6 tomcats, logging (log4j2) is configured to use SocketAppender
- The listener for these is the logstash agent that puts the logged events on the Redis
- Another logstash agent picks entries from Redis and pushes them to elasticsearch

The problem we have at times is that the client sockets (log4j loggers) sometimes wait indefinitely causing the application to become unresponsive. One of the suggested solutions was to get away from socket appenders and use local file (we don't need "instant" log info in kibana). So the logstash agent would be configured to read from 6 files (one per instance) and push these straight into elastic search. Can you suggest any disadvantages of this approach other than having 6 files defined in input configuration of logstash? What other options can you suggest? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely not use SocketAppender if you have the choice to do so. One issue being the one you mentioned and another one if you are on Logstash 1.5x or before, which I find much more troublesome, is that the exact timestamp of your event (as created by log4j2) is not conveyed, which means that the timestamp of your log line will be the arrival time of that log line in logstash instead of the time at which the log line was created by your application. If you're aggregating logs from different apps/servers/subsystems in your stack, it will be a hassle to make sense of the temporality of your events. This was [fixed in Logstash 2.0](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-log4j/commit/a7509e0bef3224caee04020b8d00f21f159df70f), though, but still worth mentioning.

Aside from that, there are at least three good reasons for storing the logs into a file on the filesystem instead of shipping them directly via TCP:

1. Your log files act as a de facto backup of your log events, i.e. you can replay those files anytime you wish
2. Your application doesn't depend on another synchronous sub-system for sending its log lines, it just sinks them on its own file system
3. Your logstash can be down (upgrade, network connectivity, etc) and your app will still be able to produce logs, no matter what's going on down the chain.

Comment: These exactly were the reasons to move from SocketAppender. Thank you!

Comment: Would be good to hear more opinions - I've seen a few articles with Redis acting as a broker between multiple log files and logstash indexer so want to confirm there's no harm in moving away from Socket->Redis->Logstash->ElasticSearch straight to MultipleFiles->Logstash->ElasticSearch

Comment: Yes, it's still a good idea to have some kind of "durable buffer" (redis, rabbitmq, kafka, etc) between your logs and Elasticsearch. It allows to scale much more robustly. See [my answer to another similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112234/documents-lost-between-logstash-and-elasticsearch/33116476#33116476) regarding having a durable "buffer". But in your case you don't need to remove your redis component, you can definitely keep it, just that your logstash agent will be reading from files instead of from SocketAppender, that's the only thing that's changing.

Comment: @Konstantin hi we are also using the file input instead of the "direct" network based approach mainly for the reasons Val already posted. I'd like to point you to one downside of the File-Input that did cost me dear however. At least under windows it is causing problems with regard to file locking. Previous to logstash 1.5 it did really lock the files it was processing, that was fixed, but it is still locking the directories where the files are residing which you need to consider when you are setting up scripts to rotate/move/... your app's log-files.

Comment: @markus Thanks markus luckily we don't use windows at all - and I was also thinking to run tail in background which will tail log file to the network disk. tail also supports log rotation so shouldn't cause much trouble - we'll see!