# Storing and managing Forex trading tick data

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, trading

I'm building a data visualization system for Forex trading and I'm exploring ways of storing the historical Forex trading tick data that I have.

The data are in the form of currency pair (e.g. USD/CAD) chronological ticks of Ask and Bid prices. At the end of the day I need my data to be indexed in Elasticsearch and what I searching for is the best way to get them there.

I found a couple of approaches online; they start out simple but then get complicated. I'm wondering if adding that extra complexity is worth it. Some of my options are:

1. Storing tick data on PostgreSQL and then via a plugin sync them to Elasticsearch ([here](https://github.com/zombodb/zombodb))
2. Storing tick data on PostgreSQL, push them to Logstash and then to Elasticsearch
3. Finally, storing tick data on PostgreSQL, push them to Redis, then to Logstash, and then to Elasticsearch

My intuition says that solution No 2 would be the ideal one, but what is considered best practice?

Comment: Rather depends on how you're receiving the tick data. Via stream for near real-time analytics, or end of day data dumps. If you're streaming, it may be worth going for a tick database such as InfluxDB. If all you're doing is indexing an end-of-day data dump, I'm not sure there's any point in having any layer between source and ElasticSearch. Also for streams, look at Kafka or RabbitMQ for open source options.

Comment: Thanks! Currently I'm working with end of day data dumps. There's a thought though to support real-time data in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good idea to store your data in a long-term storage DB, such as PostgreSQL or similar. That way you can decide at any time whether you need to change your mappings, add fields, remove fields, change their types, or what have you, and then you can easily rebuild your ES index/indices without too much trouble from your primary source of truth (i.e. PostgreSQL) and you always have clean data in ES.

I don't know ZomboDB (solution 1) so I can't really speak for it, all I know is that I'm generally not too fond of tying two different technologies together, it makes it hard to upgrade any of them in case you need/must/want to apply patches or benefit from new features in either of them.

Unless you have big and costly transformations to do on your source data, I feel that solution 3 doesn't bring much, i.e. the additional step of storing data in an intermediary Redis, doesn't bring much in my opinion (your mileage may vary here). It's a [good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112234/documents-lost-between-logstash-and-elasticsearch/33116476#33116476) to use a temporary store, such as Redis or Kafka, when you **may** lose data along the pipeline, but in this case, since you have your data in PostgreSQL, you don't really run the risk of losing anything. If at all, you can relaunch your pipeline and rebuild a few days of data.

That leaves solution 2, which would be fine given the information at hand. Using the Logstash [JDBC input](https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-jdbc-input-plugin), you can easily retrieve the latest changes and forward them to ES every x minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Eric from ZomboDB here.  I wanted to try and answer your question as it relates to ZDB.

ZomboDB is really designed for full-text searching within Postgres.  It's important to note that it's not a tool to synchronize your PG data to Elasticsearch.  It's a fully-functional Postgres index type (akin to the built-in types like btree, gin, and gist) that happens to be backed by Elasticsearch.  The fact that ZomboDB uses Elasticsearch is really an implementation detail.

While ZDB does provide a number of UDFs that expose access to ES' aggregate facilities, again, it's really designed for text searching.

So if your data is really just pairs of numbers, you're probably better off using ES directly -- especially if you're loading in one batch per day.  There's no doubt that ZDB could provide superior aggregate performance compared to standard Postgres "GROUP BY" queries (because it passes it through to Elasticsearch), but you're paying a heavy operational penalty for a limited use-case.

If, on the other hand, your ask/bid data comes with a lot of related metadata, and:

1. You need PG to be your source of truth,
2. You need to text-search that metadata (with or without aggregation support), and
3. You don't want to learn ES and introduce another database system    to your application, then...

... ZomboDB could be right for you.

I suspect Stack Overflow isn't the place to get into this, so feel free to contact me via the ways ZDB's github page recommends.